# Stacked Chart not stacking into a single bar by date

Tags: teechart

I have a dataset which returns data like below

**Date, Area, Sales**

2017-06-01 00:00:00.000 Canteen 435.29

2017-06-01 00:00:00.000 Gym 26

2017-06-01 00:00:00.000 Nails   75

2017-06-01 00:00:00.000 Uncategorized   482.5

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart using this data

The number of series will be different

I have the logic below to create the series, but I am not sure how to add each value, e.g. I need the X Axis to be by date and have 2 bars.  Each bar is then stacked with 3 series, as per the above data.

```
while not tblSalesBreakdownByDate.Eof do
begin
  nIndex := objList.IndexOf(tblSalesBreakdownByDateCategory.AsString);
  if nIndex = -1  then
  begin
    objSeries := TBarSeries.Create(Self);
    objSeries.MultiBar := TMultiBar.mbStacked;
    objSeries.Title := tblSalesBreakdownByDateCategory.AsString;

    chrtBreakdownByDate.AddSeries(objSeries);
    objList.AddObject(objSeries.Title, objSeries)
  end
  else
    objSeries := objList.Objects[nIndex];

  objSeries.Add(tblSalesBreakdownByDateTotalSales.AsFloat, tblSalesBreakdownByDateTransactionDate.AsString);

  tblSalesBreakdownByDate.Next;
end;
```

When this is rendered, instead of 1 bar which is stacked, I get 3 bars

[image]

How do I get this in 1 bar stacked for the date?

Is there something special I need to with the Axis?

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives me one single stacked column:

```
uses Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries) as TBarSeries do
  begin
    MultiBar:=mbStacked;
    Marks.Hide;
    Title:='Canteen';
    Add(435, '2017-06-01');
  end;
  with Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries) as TBarSeries do
  begin
    MultiBar:=mbStacked;
    Marks.Hide;
    Title:='Gym';
    Add(25, '2017-06-01');
  end;
  with Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries) as TBarSeries do
  begin
    MultiBar:=mbStacked;
    Marks.Hide;
    Title:='Nails';
    Add(95, '2017-06-01');
  end;
  with Chart1.AddSeries(TBarSeries) as TBarSeries do
  begin
    MultiBar:=mbStacked;
    Marks.Hide;
    Title:='Uncategorized';
    Add(455, '2017-06-01');
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I think the issue is with 0s, if my user wants to see them I may need to reopen this!